# NodeJs and MySQL timestamp

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ejs

I need to create a report that will produce a list of instructors and the students that visited the lab under those instructors broken down by date.

But currently I'm adding the checkIn and checkOut time using a getTime function and saving that time as VARCHAR in MySQL because I had problems with the timestamp in MySQL and every check in/check out is it's own row. I'm also afraid that I won't be able to use that data to produce the report correctly.

How can I make it to where when someone checks in a row is created and when they check out later their previous row is updated with the current datetime as checkOut?

```
// Checking In/Out users
router.post("/checkin", (req, res) => {

const id = req.body.create_id
const firstName = req.body.create_first_name
const lastName = req.body.create_last_name
const checkIn = getDateTime();
const checkOut = getDateTime();

console.log("Checking In...")
console.log("ID: " + req.body.create_id)
console.log("First Name: " + req.body.create_first_name)
console.log("Last Name: " + req.body.create_last_name)
console.log(checkIn)
console.log(checkOut)

// Checking Student In
    if(req.body.person === "Student" && req.body.checkInOut === "checkIn") {
      queryString = "INSERT INTO students ( student_id ,firstName, lastName, checkIn) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)"

      getConnection().query(queryString, [id, firstName, lastName, checkIn], (err, rows, fields) => {
        // If error occures 
        if(err) {
          console.log("Failed to check in new user: " + err)
          res.sendStatus(500)
          return
        }
        console.log("Checked in new user with id: ", id)
      })
    }

    // Checking Student Out
    else if(req.body.person === "Student" && req.body.checkInOut === "checkOut") {
      queryString = "INSERT INTO students ( student_id ,firstName, lastName, checkOut) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)"

      getConnection().query(queryString, [id, firstName, lastName, checkOut], (err, rows, fields) => {
        // If error occures 
        if(err) {
          console.log("Failed to check out new user: " + err)
          res.sendStatus(500)
          return
        }
        console.log("Checked out user with id: ", id)
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also create table like

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `is_checkout` boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
  `last_name` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

When user check in you only create one row, current_timestamp of mysql will record current date time
and when user check out you find students by id `where student.is_checkout = false` and update column `is_checkout` to `true` and at that time updated_at will be record current timestamp of checkout date

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll edit this once I get it implemented.

Comment: I got it working. How would I be able to display my MySQL data in html?

Comment: you can use moment js to parse it to string or parse it to string from server and return data to client

Comment: I got MySQL data displayed for now, if I need to make some changes I will consider it. Thank you